# TOR Browser locked in Firefox, keep getting proxy server rufusing connection

Tags: configuration, firefox, proxy, server

Please advise on how I can get rid of running TOR on Firefox. Whenever I type in a URL I get "Proxy Server Refusing Connection"

Comment: Check antivirus, firewall and other "security" software.

Comment: Thought it might be a newbie thing maybe not, I'm running a mac running Tor by itself with a VPN having the same issues.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Tor Browser? Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox via a Tor socks proxy, make sure that you have specified the correct ports in your configuration of Firefox and make sure that they all point to "localhost" at either port 9050 or 9150 as I believe they are the default ports used. Another reason may be badly configured torrc file, please have a look at that.

If you are using Tor Browser by itself, the fastest way of solving this problem is simply downloading and reinstalling. It should solve the issue.